# Laravel is unable to identify the data in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations

I use Laravel
When I try to access Localhost:8000 I get an error

```
    Illuminate\Database\QueryException
    SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'my_data' (SQL: select `title`,`id` from `table_8` where `id` = 24)
```

I have a database called my_data in phpmyadmin

```
XAMPP\volumes\root\htdocs\project\.env

 _CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE= my_data
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=
```

```
XAMPP\volumes\root\htdocs\project\config\database.php
  'mysql' => [
             'driver' => 'mysql',
             'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
             'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
             'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
             'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'my_data'),
             'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
             'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
             'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
             'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
             'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
             'prefix' => '',
             'prefix_indexes' => true,
             'strict' => true,
             'engine' => null,
             'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
             ]) : [],
         ],
```

I changed the DB_DATABASE to my_data in the .env file

And I ran the command

```
$php artisan cheat:clear
```

And yet the error is still the same error

```
    Illuminate\Database\QueryException
    SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'my_data' (SQL: select `title`,`id` from `table_8` where `id` = 24)
```

I am use Mac

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you mean you ran the command `php artisan config:clear`?

Answer (score 0):

i think your username and password of phpmyadmin is wrong. please check it out. of different. fix it. and try again